# How to make a function that does an insert but the function must handle tables with different number of columns?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm planning on making a function that when given a list and table name, it will insert the values of the list into the table. I know the maximum number of columns a table will have (for example sake let's say it's 4).

So I'd have

```
list = [col1, val1, col2, val2, col3, val3, col4, val4]
stmt = 'INSERT INTO {} ({}, {}, {}, {}) VALUES {}, {}, {}, {};'.format('myTable', list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3], list[4], list[5], list[6], list[7], list[8])
cur.execute(stmt)
```

but say for example another table only has two columns. Then if `stmt = 'INSERT INTO {} ({}, {}, {}, {}) VALUES ({}, {}, {}, {});'.format('myTable', list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3], list[4], list[5], list[6], list[7], list[8])` were in a function the program would crash as `list[7]` and `[list8]` would be out of bounds! (see what I'm saying?)

In the example I have a simple list but currently the program has a list inside a list of the format `[[val1, colName1], [val2, colName2],...,[valn, colNamen]]` where `vali` is the value to go into `coli` and all of this will be on the same row in a table.

The problem is made more complicated because a value to be inserted may have experienced an error and be `NoneType`. Since you can't insert a null into Postgres, this would be an issue.

Comment: In case of a None/NULL shall we skip the column in the INSERT?

Comment: @Pynchia yes that's what normally is done, but if you're trying to make a function that just substitutes in the values to insert using `{}` how can it be skipped? For example in Python if the code looks like `cur.execute('INSERT INTO tableA col1 VALUES {}'.format(arg))` (where `arg` is passed as argument to function this is in) then how would you just "skip" it?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Have a look and tell me if it is acceptable now

Comment: All the code in this question is scary bad.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, which skips None values

```
def insert_stmt(table, l):
    vals = ['"'+str(el)+'"' for n, el in enumerate(l) if l[n] and n % 2]
    if not vals:
        return ""
    cols = [el for n, el in enumerate(l) if n < (len(l)-1) and l[n+1] \
                                            and not n % 2]
    stmt = 'INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({});'.format(table,
                                                   ', '.join(cols),
                                                   ', '.join(vals))
    return stmt

lst = ['col1', 1, 'col2', None, 'col3', 3, 'col4', None]
print insert_stmt('mytable', lst)

lst_none = ['col1', None, 'col2', None]
print insert_stmt('mytable', lst_none)
```

produces

```
INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col3) VALUES ("1", "3");
<empty string>
```

It assumes the column names are strings.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Python, where does `el` come from and what does it mean when something comes before a `for` loop?

Comment: please tell me if my solution solves the problem or not. If it does, please accept the answer (if it is the best/most suitable answer in your opinion, of course).

Comment: about the python syntax I used: those are called `list comprehensions`. Such statements build lists according to a given condition. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk). It's an interesting an long subject to be explained here in full. Search online/study a book for more resources about Python's iterators, generators comprehensions, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been busy and still am going through the test cases.

Comment: On line 3 you have your quotes inverted `'"'` needs to be `"'"`

Comment: The function doesn't handle the situation where all values are null, if this is the situation the empty string should be returned (or whatever signal for failure you see best).

Comment: OK. I thought you wanted help on how to handle the problem, not a production-ready solution. That said, now it handles the "all-None" case. As you can see, it's fairly easy to check.

Comment: @Celeritas the quotes work fine either way in python. I use the double quotes in the SQL statement, as Django does, for example.

Comment: What makes you say the quotes work fine either way? Single quotes and double quotes make a difference in Postgres.

Comment: Also `VALUES {}` must be `VALUES ({})`

Comment: I see, easy to fix. correct it in your question then, I copied the SQL from that

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
    a = ['col1', '1']
    b = ['col2', '2']
    c = [a, b]
    col_val = zip(c)
    stmt = 'INSERT INTO {}({}) VALUES {};'.format('myTable', 
                                                 ", ".join(col_val[0]),
                                                 ", ".join(col_val[1]))
    cur.execute(stmt)
```

Obviously you might need to tweak it. I'd recommend learning something like SQLAlchemy though if you plan on doing much SQL stuff. Makes like easier.

Dealing with NoneType? Just doing some checking before inserting..?